# LINQ SUM data based on Array Results

Tags: c#, linq

I'm stuck on this issue. I know it can be done nicely with LINQ (I don't want to use multiple foreach loops), but I simply cannot get it to work. Here is the problem:

I have two classes:

Class **Invoice**

```
public class Invoice
{
public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

public Invoice(int ID, string sName, DateTime dt_Date)
{
    this.InvoiceID = ID;
    this.Name = sName;
    this.DueDate = dt_Date;
}
}
```

and Class **Activity**

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Activity(int ID, int InvoiceID, int iCount, double dPrice)
    {
        this.ActivityID = ID;
        this.InvoiceID = InvoiceID;
        this.Count = iCount;
        this.Price = dPrice;
    }
}
```

The logic is that Each Invoice contains multiple Activities. E.g. you have a bill from a shop (Invoice), which includes items such as bread, butter, milk (Activities).

What I want to do is that based on user selected Date, I want to return total amount paid (basically I want to perform SUM of all bills from specific Date period).

Here is what I have:

```
//user selected DateTime - for the sake of test we make it current day
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now;

//Retrieve invocies that match user selected Date
var retrievedInvoices = invList
  .Where(n => n.DueDate.ToShortDateString() == selectedDate.ToShortDateString());
```

This is fine, as we have retrieved list of all Invoices based on desired Date. But now? I tried something as following:

```
//now make SUM of activities that match retrievedInvoices -> look at their 
//ID's and if match is found, then multiply price x count
double dResult = invActivity
    .Where(n => retrievedInvoices.Where(x=>x.InvoiceID == n.InvoiceID))
    .Sum(n => n.Price * n.Count);
```

But it is not working. I am not that proficient in LINQ so there might be more elegant way of doing it (maybe in one line of code) but I don't know.

Could you guys help me with this one, please?

**EDIT:**

Interesting thing to note also for others that might be looking at this thread: I have first tried to use List in order to retrieve my list of invoices that match specific time period (DateTime_From and DateTime_To); but it behaved strangely as sometimes it worker correctly, sometimes not (even though the code was correct). After I changed `List <Invoice> retrievedInvoice` to `var retrievedInvoice` it suddenly worked without a problem. I don't understand why this is so, but I will definitely be more aware next time of what type do I use.
Thanks again folks!

Comment: Tip: the phrase "it is not working" does not fly here. _Describe_ how it does not work to your expectations.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What `invList` object is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but try some changes like this:

use .Date to compare just Dates without Time (hours, minutes, etc..) and select just eh `InvoiceID` proeprty into a `array`

```
var retrievedInvoices = invList.Where(n => n.DueDate.Date == selectedDate.Date)
                               .Select(x => x.InvoiceID);
```

use `.Contains()` to check the condition which return a bool value.

```
double dResult = invActivity
    .Where(n => retrievedInvoices.Contains(n.InvoiceID))
    .Sum(n => n.Price * n.Count);
```

Some changes was suggested by `Tuespetre` user in comments bellow!

Comment: Why not select all of the invoice IDs matching the criteria and use a contains instead of Any?

Comment: By calling `ToArray()`, the query is executed. If you leave off `ToArray()`, LINQ *should* be smart enough to put in a subquery (`... WHERE InvoiceId IN (SELECT InvoiceId FROM Invoices WHERE ...)`)

Comment: Nice, I know it works with NHibernate, is it works with Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. For an example, see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443122/entity-framework-subquery

They declare the subquery inline instead of a previous variable like you have (I prefer the previous variable over inline, easier to read) and when you think about how it is parsed, EF will see a contains and then determine whether it is `IQueryable` or not. If it is `IQueryable`, it can build a SQL subquery, but if not, then it has to autofill a whole bunch of parameters for each item in the array or list.