# Write LINQ query to this SQL query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to write LINQ query to this SQL query:

```
select * from tbl_BILLING_PricingGenerations pg
where pg.GenerationID = (
    select ChangeToGenerationId
    from tbl_BILLING_PricingGenerations where GenerationID = 2
)
```

Comment: what have you tired?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443122/entity-framework-subquery)

Comment: Is there a reason this written as a subquery and not a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following tool may help you, for this query and many other: http://sqltolinq.com/

Here you can download a **Linqer** tool to solve your problem. But not sure if it works for all kind of SQL queries.